# click event is called in many times on rails jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use JavaScript to toggle the visibility of an element when clicking on another element.

This is my JavaScript so far:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ticket_title', function(event){  
    console.log("click!")
    $("#ticket_sub_"+$(this).attr("data-id")).slideToggle();
});
```

However it isn't working correctly, as the click event gets triggered multiple times.

This is my html so far:

```
<div id="ticket_56" class="ticket_box">
    <div class="ticket_title" data-id="56"></div>
</div>
<div id="ticket_sub_56" style="display:none;" class="ticket_sub">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using rails 4?

Comment: Can you paste an HTML snippet so we can see the element you're clicking and the element you're toggling relate to each other?

Comment: yes !! I use rails 4.

Comment: I think it is maybe caused by turbolink.

Answer (score 1):

sorry this error is caused by turbolinks.

turbolinks is called js at page move.
so js bind one document in many times.

so I resolve this problem to unbind document before bind document.

```
$(document).off("click", ".ticket_title");
$(document).on('click', '.ticket_title', function(event){
    $("#ticket_sub_"+$(this).attr("data-id")).slideToggle();
});
```

thanks to your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).on('click', '.ticket_title', function(event){  
console.log("click!");
doc="#ticket_sub_"+$(this).attr("data-id");
$(doc).slideToggle();
});
```

Try will work fine.

Comment: I checked it. it working fine with me. Issue might be with the JQ version